# What items can I find in Die2Nite?

Tags: die2nite

Items in the town bank seem to be broken in to four categories: Resources, Armoury, Furniture, and Miscellaneous. However I haven't been able to find a list of what items can be found or what they actually do. Is there an item list anywhere?

Comment: This question is already the top result for die2nite items on google. Wow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die2Nite Wiki has a list of items! And it seems fairly comprehensive too.

You can find it [here](http://die2nite.wikia.com/wiki/Items).